# python FindWindow by hex value

Tags: python, hex, findwindow

I run this code and get a list of all windows in return.

```
def winEnumHandler(hwnd, ctx):
    if win32gui.IsWindowVisible(hwnd):
        # print(hex(hwnd), win32gui.GetWindowText(hwnd))
        print(
            "{:} - [{:}] - {:}".format(hex(hwnd), win32gui.GetWindowText(hwnd),
                                       hex(win32gui.GetWindowLong(hwnd,
                                                                  win32con.GWL_EXSTYLE))))
```

**Result: 0x306be - [Calculator] - 0x200100**

Now I am trying to run:

```
window = win32gui.FindWindow(None, 0x306be)
```

It doesn't find it by the hex value. Is there a way to use **0x306be** or **0x200100** to find the window? I have A few windows with the same name and I am not sure how to make it find the correct one besides using one of those values.

Answer (score 0):

You got 0x306be by converting the integer inside hwnd to a hex value, which win32gui.findWindow() cannot read. It can however read an integer so you can use hwnd instead.

window = win32gui.FindWindow(None, hwnd)